# CAAnimation trouble

Tags: ios, view, core-animation, caanimation

I am planning on using `CAAnimation` to switch views but I am confused on how to actually do this. I know `CAAnimation` works by using a to and from Value so how would I move a UIView by using `toValue` and `fromValue`. Lets say I want to mimic the `UINavigationController`'s `pushViewController`, how would I do this using `CAAnimation` like I mentioned above?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the simple animation, you can use the `UIView` APIs, like `beginAnimations:context:`

About `CAAnimation`, you can get the sample from doc reference

Comment: I can't, I must use Core Animation in my case :[